# UITableView selection -- multiple selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a strange uitableview selection problem. Attempting to use multiple selection with a couple cells preselected. Multiple selection is set to true.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 15.0f];
    cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //    if([_selectedInts containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.row]]){
    //
    //        [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
    //
    //    } else {
    //
    //        [cell setSelected:NO animated:NO];
    //
    //    }


    return cell;
}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


    if([_selectedInts containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)indexPath.row]]){

        [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {

        [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

}
```

When the tableview loads a bunch of cells are selected due to a list of integers marking the indexes that need to be selected.

These cells stop being responsive and don't issue the didselect and diddeselect methods upon getting tapped.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why putting that code in willDisplayCell cause that to happen, but I found the same thing when I tried your code. Putting the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath: worked if I used selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: instead of setSelected: (the cells didn't show the selection color if I used setSelected:, but they were responsive). So this code worked to show the checkmarks and selection color, and changed that state correctly when selecting or deselecting other cells. Notice also that I dequeue cells, since that is more memory efficient then the way you're creating your cells,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 15.0f];
    cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([_selectedInts containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]){
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.selectedInts addObject:@(indexPath.row)];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.selectedInts removeObject:@(indexPath.row)];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method, do you really need to create new cell whenever cells are visible?

Let's try, this is the best practice recommended by Apple:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"a";
return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps you